# 'Widget?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, provider, flutter-provider

when i assign consumer `child:ch` that time error shown this:- `The argument type 'Widget?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'`

The code is :

```
...
Consumer<Cart>(
            builder: (_, cart, ch) => Badge(
                child: ch,
                value: cart.iteamCount.toString(),
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `ch` is a Widget which is nullable i.e it's defined as `Widget?`.

So to avoid this , one work around is add not null operator `!`

Change

```
child: ch
```

to

```
child: ch!
```